# How to insert records to a many to many relationship table on an sql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web, many-to-many

I just started PHP and am encountering a problem with php where the sql command shown below does not execute (inserts records into a many to many relationship table) when calling it with php while it works perfectly when manually inserting it with mysql command line interface.
I am using $ds and $da (manual inputs) instead of making use of sessions to make sure that the command is executed. Noting that I have other mysql queries and work perfectly fine when executed through php using the same database connection as the one shown hereunder.

```
$connectionStatua = connect_db();
mysqli_query($connectionStatus, $sql);

$username = $_SESSION["username"];
$ds = "dekna";
$da = "dsa.jpg";
$query="INSERT INTO `tbl_users_files` (`user_ID`, `file_ID`)
SELECT `u.id`, `f.id` FROM `users` as `u` CROSS JOIN `tbl_uploads` as `f`
WHERE `username` = '$ds' AND `file` = '$da'";
mysqli_query($connectionStatus, $query);
```

Please take a look at the structure of my tables:
[mySql tables structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2sEI.png)

Also, evidence that the command works perfectly in mysql cli can be viewed here: ("dekna" has id 1 while dsa.jpg has id 44 - hence take a look at the last record):
[mySql cli - Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG3nr.png)

Comment: Add `or die(mysqli_error($connectioNStatus);` to the end of the `mysqli_query` lines so you will see any error messages from the database.

Comment: In connect_db() function I have added to echo all errors thrown by the system but unfortunately none are thrown. I know for sure that it works since I have sql queries in my php code and they work perfectly. The error detection also works as I have tried to insert dummy data and errors came up but not for this one unfortunately.

Comment: `mysqli` doesn't report SQL errors as system errors. You have to test for those errors explicitly.

Comment: Oh I see, I have added it and the error showing up says the following: Unknown column 'u.id' in 'field list'

Comment: Can you show the table structures for these tables? What all columns do you have in each tables. Also, your $query looks confusing so please show the table structures. If you say that this works perfectly on mysql command line, then you might want to replace the ` with ' (e.g. `tbl_users_files`  with 'tbl_users_files' )

Comment: Since I am new to StackOverflow I can't add photos as yet, therefore I have provided a link (provided by stackoverflow) to where the photo with the tables structure is saved.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/G2sEI.png

Comment: That's not a problem, I see your tables now. Correct me if I am wrong: 1> User logs in (and you can get this username from session). 2> This user uploads a file and so you get a file name. You store this file name in tbl_uploads. 3> You want to get the id for this file name just inserted in tbl_uploads and id of the logged in user from users table and want to add these as user_ID and file_ID in the tbl_users_files. Is that what you need here?

Comment: Yes @CaptainRed, that's exactly what I intend to do. As I said I am not using _SESSION["username"] and the current file name just to make sure the sqli query is working fine .. keeping in mind that dekna and dsa.jpg are indeed in the database

Comment: I have just ran the same command on mysql cli again and it works perfectly as shown in the photo below:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/fG3nr.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1> Get (Select) id of the user from the users table:

Step 2> Get (Select) id of the file from tbl_uploads table:

Step 3> Insert user_ID (from step 1) and file_ID (from step 2) to tbl_users_files table:

```js
$connectionStatua = connect_db();
mysqli_query($connectionStatus, $sql);

$username = $_SESSION["username"]; //or $ds = "dekna";
$da = "dsa.jpg";

$user_ID = $file_ID = null;

//STEP 1
$query1="SELECT id FROM 'users' WHERE username = '$username'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connectionStatus, $query1);

if( mysqli_num_rows($result1 ) > 0)
  {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
     $user_ID = $row['id'];
    }
      
  }
//STEP 2
$query2="SELECT id FROM 'tbl_uploads' WHERE file = '$da'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connectionStatus, $query2);

if( mysqli_num_rows($result2 ) > 0)
  {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
     $file_ID = $row['id'];
    }
      
  }
//STEP 3
$query3 ="INSERT INTO tbl_users_files (user_ID, file_ID) values('$user_ID' , '$file_ID')";

mysqli_query($connectionStatus, $query3);
```

Comment: After some amendments to the script provided by you @Captain Red I have managed to get it working. The mistakes I amended in your code were as follows: 

1) table and column names must be within ` ` instead of ' ' 

2) mysqli_num_rows($query1) > 0 should be mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0 ... the result should be passed as an argument not the command.

Apart from that, it works perfectly.

Comment: I am still wondering what was the error in my code though .. is it because php only handles single commands and not joint commands?

Comment: Yes, I did suggest you to replace the ` with ' in my comment above. And yes the result should be the argument, I have edited this now. I haven't done plain php for a while now. Glad that you got it working.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort! Many thanks @Captain Red. Regards

Comment: Not a problem. Keep coding! Regards-